# Sys.exit() throwing a syntax error

Tags: python, sys

I'm creating a function that checks input and exits if input is not in the correct form. However, I'm getting an error that sys.exit() is 'invalid syntax'. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import re 
import sys

def my_program(x):
# takes input in form '#d#'
    if re.match('\d\w\d', x ) is False:
        print('Format of input must be '#d#')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting...

Comment: copy and paste the stack trace.  FYI, the code you have there runs as written for me.

Comment: Word of advice: don't use syntax like `is False`. Rather, prepend the condition with `not`. -> `if not re.match(...):`

Comment: `re.match()` doesn't return `False` on failure, it returns `None` -- not the syntax error you're looking for but an error that will keep the `if` from firing.  The advice regarding `not` from @pushkin would have also covered the `None` case.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not with `sys.exit()`, but with the line above it.

You have an extra quote.

```
print('Format of input must be #d#')
```

Comment: I fixed the quotes but it's still giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to either escape the strings in the print statement or use the mix of single and double quotes in the print statement. The `sys.exit()` looks good.

```
print('Format of input must be \'#d#\'')
```

or

```
print("Format of input must be '#d#'")
```

Comment: Even with the quotes fixed I get the same error

Comment: @boson, Can you paste the new code and complete error?